# how to check if 3 digit code is already exists in sample ajax function using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, bootstrapvalidator

I need to check the given code is already exists or not through ajax function by using Jquery, and the ajax file structure how can values should be mentioned dummy code's and how to write that kind of validation scripting.
This is Jquery validation the entering values in input box without submitting the submit button.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action=" " method="post"  id="contact_form">
  <fieldset>
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group margin0 col-sm-4">
      <label class="col-sm-12 pad0 control-label">Schedule Name</label>  
      <div class="col-md-12 pad0 inputGroupContainer mt-10">
        <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
          <input  name="schedule_name" id="schedulename" placeholder="Schedule Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group margin0 col-sm-3">
      <label class="col-sm-12 pad0 control-label">Schedule Code</label>  
      <div class="col-md-12 pad0 inputGroupContainer mt-10">
        <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
          <input name="schedulecode" id="schedulecode" placeholder="Schedule Code" class="form-control"  type="number">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group margin0 col-sm-3">
      <label class="col-sm-12 pad0 control-label">Schedule Number</label>  
      <div class="col-md-12 pad0 inputGroupContainer mt-10">
        <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
          <input name="scheduleno" id="scheduleno" placeholder="Schedule Number" class="form-control"  type="number">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- radio checks -->
    <div class="form-group margin0 col-sm-2">
      <label class="col-sm-12 pad0 control-label">Inheritance</label>
      <div class="col-sm-12 inherit pad0">
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="assest" required /> Asset
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="liability" required /> Liability
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="income" required /> Income
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="expenses" required /> Expense
          </label>
        </div>
        <p class="radioerr"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="form-group margin0 text-center">
      <div class="col-md-12 pad0">
        <button type="submit" class="btn add-btn submit-btn" id="alert-done" >Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default add-btn" id="reset-btn" >Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert" style="display: none;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
      <strong>Success! </strong> Product have added to your wishlist.
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

My script is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
    fields: {
      schedule_name: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 2,
          },
          regexp: {
            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z-0-9,]+(\s{0,1}[a-zA-Z-, %,a-zA-Z-0-9])*$/,
            message: 'The full name can consist of alphabetical characters, numbers, % and Whitespaces only'
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please enter valid name'
          }
        }
      },
      schedulecode: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 3,
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please enter valid code'
          }
        }
      },
      scheduleno: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            max: 3,
            min: 3,
            ajax:{
              url:'data.txt',
              type:'post',
              error: function()
              {
                message:'file not exists'
              },
              success: function()
              {
                message:'file exists'
              }
            }
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please enter valid number'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
    $('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow"); // Do something ...
    $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
    // Prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the form instance
    var $form = $(e.target);
    // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
    var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');
    // Use Ajax to submit form data
    $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }, 'json');
  });
```

Comment: After indenting your code, it looks like there's some issue with your code. Would you mind checking that?

Comment: yeah issue in ajax script is wrong, i don't know how to write the ajax scripting for checking the value is exists or not.
please show some examples

Comment: Updated tags as this appears to be specific to the boostrapvalidator

Comment: Might be something in one of these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbootstrapvalidator%5D+ajax

Comment: freedomn-m  thanks bro